# .htaccess is not working on new server if rewrite rule matches redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

On our new server some .htaccess rewrite rules do not work anymore. They work fine on our old server and in my local environment.
The problem seems to occur if the rewrite condition matches the rewrite destination:

```
# Examples, 1st and 2nd rule where not together in one file
# Does not work
RewriteRule ^wartung/?$ wartung.php [L,NC,QSA]

# Does work
RewriteRule ^wartung/?$ test_wartung.php [L,NC,QSA]

# Does not work
RewriteRule ^produkte/?$ produkte.php [L,NC,QSA]

# Does work
RewriteRule ^kundenkonto/?$ service.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

Where is my mistake?
Further tests have shown that all rules do not work which have this pattern

```
RewriteRule ^something/?$ something.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

Those work
Further tests have shown that all rules do not work which have this pattern

```
RewriteRule ^something/?$ something_else.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

But I don't get why?

Happy new year to everyone!!

Comment: I think 2nd Rule will NOT work is obvious since if 1st Rule is getting succeeded then it will never to 2nd hence its NOT working(see condition part `^wartung/?$` is same in 1st and 2nd rules), I doubt it would have ever worked IMHO. For your 4th rule(2nd not working rule) could you please make sure that file `service.php` is present in your same path where your htaccess file is present? Kindly do let know on same, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks for your comment. 1st and 2nd rule where just examples, they did not appear together.
.htaccess and all files are in the same folder.

Comment: could you please confirm once if files `wartung.php` AND `produkte.php` are present in same with where .htaccess resides?(but again your 1st and 2nd rule's left side(condition part) is same so only 1 of them will be working, mostly first rule if your file  `wartung.php`  is found).

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks. I understood. This does not work: `RewriteRule ^wartung/?$ wartung.php [L,NC,QSA]`. But if I REPLACE it with this `RewriteRule ^wartung/?$ test_wartung.php [L,NC,QSA]` it works.
All files wartung.php, produkte.php, service.php and test_wartung.php are in the same folder

Comment: Ok, then I will go with my next question. Could you please do let me know(sample URLs only) which urls you are hitting so that I could understand it better, thank you.

Comment: Thank you once again. I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. E.g. mypage.de/wartung (you can test this). At the moment all found pages are redirected (not via .htaccess) to a guy with a coffee mug

Comment: Could you please mention like which URLs should be served by which php file in backend, eg--> `http://localhost:80/test_singh` --> `http://localhost:80/index.php` etc, thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226831/discussion-between-phantom-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: This is just a reduced sample:
`https://www.example.org/wartung --> https://www.example.org/wartung.php`,
`https://www.example.org/produkte --> https://www.example.org/produkte.php`,
`https://www.example.org/kundenkonto --> https://www.example.org/service.php`

Comment: As that all rule with this pattern do not work: `RewriteRule ^something/?$ something.php ` All others do

Comment: Try disabling multiviews on your server. Add the following line to your htaccess `Options -Multiviews` I think this will solve your issue.

Comment: @AmitVerma Thank you very much! This solves my issue! That's really great!